# how to access the nocollapsed object name ( compiled with closure-util)

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

i wroted the script code and compile with closure-util. 
but, i can not access the instanciated object's sub object. 
how to fix or write code?
i included my code below...

---

> main.js

---

```
goog.provide('org');
goog.provide('org.com');

/** @constructor */
org.com = function(){
    this.name = "com";
    console.log("created org.com");
}

/** @constructor */
org.com.init = function() {
    console.log("org.com.init!!");

    var obj = new org.com();
    obj.init();
    return obj
};

org.com.prototype.init = function(){
    console.log("org.com.prototype.init");

    try {
        this.biz1 = new org.com.biz1;
    } catch (e$1) {
        this.biz1 = undefined;
    }

    if (this.biz1 != undefined) {
        console.log("call biz1.prototype.init...");
        this.biz1.init(this);//
    }
}

/** @constructor */
org.com.biz1 = function(){
    this.name = "biz1";
    console.log("org.com.biz1");
}

org.com.biz1.prototype.init = function(parent){
    console.log("org.com.biz1.prototype.init");
}

goog.exportSymbol('org.com',org.com);
goog.exportSymbol('org.com.init',org.com.init);
goog.exportSymbol('org.com.biz1',org.com.biz1);

goog.exportProperty(org.com.prototype,'init',org.com.prototype.init);
goog.exportProperty(org.com.biz1.prototype,'init',org.com.biz1.prototype.init);
```

---

> config.json

---

"output_wrapper": "(function(){%output%})();"

---

> index.html (chrome debug console)

---

```
> org
{com: ƒ}
--com: ƒ of()
----biz1: ƒ pf()
----init: ƒ ()
```

this is ok! what i expected.

```
> var obj = new org.com.init()
> obj
of {name: "com", a: pf}
--a: pf {name: "biz1"}
--name: "com"
```

> **of** --> org.com  (i want to expected 'com' instead of 'of' )
>
> **a**  --> org.com.biz1 (i want to expected 'biz1' instead of 'a' )

**please, how to fix (or write code) for this?**

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack. Are you wanting to disable the property renaming entirely (see `@export`), or simply retain evidence of what the original name was (maybe add a string to the objects)?

Comment: i thanks for your comment. i want not to rename the objects that i just  want to show only. however, as i included code, the object(biz1) is instanciated after use 'new' is renamed. so, how to rewrite code? please, show me the code...